# Eclipse Not Showing Any Syntax Errors or Any Red Markers

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

[image]

As per the screenshot it is not displaying any errors and I am just creating a maven project and trying to create a class file and am trying to type something in the class, but it is not showing any kind of errors. Please Help me. 
And this is what showing in build path. Please help me how to solve this !!

Comment: Why are differently named projects shown? Have you looked into why it marked the SpringSample/src/main/java as "(missing)"? Is your pom.xml out of date? What does the Maven property page hierarchy show?

Comment: FYI, I cannot read your screenshot.

Comment: This problem persists only for Maven projects .... I don't understand what is wrong ...

Answer (score 3):

Open your projects Build path (`Project > Properties > Java Build Path`) [Java Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm) make sure following:

1. Your source folder is there in Source tab of build path.
2. Goto **Libraries tab** and check for correct JRE version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project folder in eclipse workspace and run following command.
Refresh the project afterwards.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Check <kbd>`Project`</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>`Build Automatically`</kbd> menu, also try <kbd>`Project`</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>`Clean`</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I think you should try updating your eclipse. which version you are using? There could be a possibility of missing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build path -> Configure Build Path and check the libraries tab for any jar missing. This worked for me rather than cleaning and building again.